# Converting between number systems with arbitrary base

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

Consider a situation, in which the following function is required:

```
convert(val1, base1, base2)
```

It converts a number (`val1`) from `base1` number system to `base2` number system. In this function, all arguments are strings, e.g.

```
convert("34", "012345", "01234567890ABCDEF")
```

Is called in order to convert 34<sub>6</sub> -> X<sub>16</sub>.

When I started thinking of implementation, it came obvious that converting a number with a bigger base to a smaller one requires division operation defined for numbers in the bigger base, e.g. 12<sub>10</sub> -> X<sub>2</sub> = 12 / 2 | 6 / 2 | 3 / 2 | 1 / 2 | = 1100<sub>2</sub>.

The next though was about doing 2-step-conversion X<sub>b1</sub> -> X<sub>10</sub> -> X<sub>b2</sub>. This would be definitely easier to implement, but guys, can you please confirm that I'm not wrong in previous conclusion, or is there a clear way to implement such `convert()` function without an intermediate to-decimal conversion?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your programming language of choice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a practical solution in a computer program, you don't want to convert to base 10 as an intermediate, but instead convert to the computer's native representation, the base of which is irrelevant. Write two separate functions, one to parse a string into an integer, the other to convert an integer to a string.

Comment: Thank you Russell, Good point of converting to binary instead of decimal as intermediate.

Comment: But from the practical point of view, I'd still write the code that converts to base 10.

Comment: Why? Walk the string from right to left, multiplying by the radix of the input base (6 in your example) and adding the value of the character at each step. That gives you a native machine integer. Then do successive div-and-mod by the radix of the output base (16 in your example) to build up the output string right to left. Base 10 is not involved at all unless you decide to print the intermediate as a sanity check.

Comment: I think this is backwards:  "Walk the string from right to left, multiplying by the radix of the input base (6 in your example) and adding the value of the character at each step."  It should be left to right.  If you take "123" in base-6, and reduce the characters right-to-left, you'll end up with 121 (`1 + 6 * (2 + 6 * (3 + 6 * 0)) = 121`).  But if you reduce left-to-right, you get 51 (`3 + 6 * (2 + 6 * (1 + 6 * 0)) = 51`).  Nevertheless, I found your comment helpful; thank you!